# Simplest form validation with the jQuery validation plugin wont work

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to learn the jQuery validation plugin, so I created the simplest possible form, with the simplest possible validation code, but I still can't get it to work! When I click the submit button (leaving the field empty), I am sent to the default page as if the form had been submitted (the URL being "myurl.com/?name=") Below is the code, which I tried to do identical to that of a working tutorial.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd'>
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://myurl.com/jquery.validate.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://myurl.com/jquery.js'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#test_form").validate();
    });
    </script>

    <script type='text/css'>
    label.error { color:Red; }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form id='test_form' action='' method='GET'>
    <p><label for='name'>Name</label><br />
    <input type='text' id='name' name='name' minlength='4' class='required' /></p>
    <p><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't you need to include the plugin after jQuery? And what is a `text/css` _script_?

Comment: +1, you also need to change that one to a `<style>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the main `jquery.js` before the plugin `jquery.validate.js`. Scripts are loaded in the order they're parsed.

The above results in a script error when trying to load the validate plugin, as jQuery is not loaded yet, the jQuery object to extend doesn't exist at the time.